# R implementation of group lasso-regularized linear regression

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

Does anyone know of any good implementation of group-lasso regularized linear regression in R (or even Matlab)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at **[GNU Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)**?  It does its work on command line so you can use it with any language that can read/write to file and execute shell commands to kick it off from within the program.

GNU Octave is featured in the **[Stanford Machine Learning Course](https://class.coursera.org/ml/lecture/preview)** on the chapter of linear regression with multiple variables.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [grplasso](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grplasso/) package in CRAN which I believe is what you are looking for.